# activity cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-activity

i'm a beginner Android developer. When I try to run my Application this error appears "

```
activity_prima cannot be resolved or is not a field PrimaActivity.java  /esempio3/src/com/example/esempio3  line 19 Java Problem ".  
and also "activity_seconda cannot be resolved or is not a field SecondaActivity.java    /esempio3/src/com/example/esempio3  line 11 Java Problem"
```

I have already put my activities in the manifest.xml but something goes wrong because my R.txt desappears very often. Here there are my java  and xlm files .

This is my **first activity java file.**

```
package com.example.esempio3;

import android.R;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

public class PrimaActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prima);

Button bottone= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bott1);
bottone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(PrimaActivity.this,       SecondaActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);      
     finish();
}
});
}


}
```

This is my **xml file**.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res   /android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sfondo1"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.esempio3.PrimaActivity" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:src="@drawable/batman3" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Benvenuto nella mia App"
    android:textColor="#FFA07A" />




<Button
    android:id="@+id/bott1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bott2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:onClick="Login"
    android:text="Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bott2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="101dp"
    android:onClick="Registrati"
    android:text="Registrati" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here there is my **second activity java file**.

```
package com.example.esempio3;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondaActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seconda);
}




}
```

my **xml file** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sfondo1"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.esempio3.SecondaActivity" >

<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">
<TableRow
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#F5F5DC"
    android:text="Username:"/>
     <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/username" />
</TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#F5F5DC"
    android:text="Password:"/>
     <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/password" />
</TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#F5F5DC"
    android:text="Indirizzo email:"/>
     <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/mail" />
</TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#F5F5DC"
    android:text="Nome:"/>
     <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/nome" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

My **manifest** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.esempio3"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".PrimaActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name=".SecondaActivity"
         >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what is your main activity layout name? is it activity_prima.xml or activity_primary.xml ?

Comment: activity_prima is my main activity.

Comment: 1. It is R.java, not R.txt..  2. it crashes at setContentView().. 3. Have you tried rebuilding R.java?

Comment: Trying to solve the several errors generated after, since the main error Was related to the fact That eclipse didn't recognize my activities i decided to start working in Android Studio. Everything works! :) I think there Was a problem of updating! Thaks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should import R of your package,maybe `com.example.esempio3.R`,not `android.R`.Just change this:

[image]

Comment: Trying to solve the several errors generated after, since the main error Was related to the fact That eclipse didn't recognize my activities i decided to start working in Android Studio. Everything works! :) I think there Was a problem of updating! Thaks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If your R.java is not generated, you can run into this kind of problem. Please check if R.java is generated.

If R.java is present, then try cleaning/rebuilding your project. Also make sure your have imported the correct R.java(because each library you have added to the project will there own R.java).

If R.java is missing, then one of the reasons might be some error in xml layout. One of the probable reasons might be that in your **first activity xml file** your namespace is wrong.It is should be `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`

Another reason can be missing resources, check all drawables,strings, dimens.. used in layout have been defined or added to the project. Also make sure none of your xml files have lint error.

Comment: Trying to solve the several errors generated after, since the main error Was related to the fact That eclipse didn't recognize my activities i decided to start working in Android Studio. Everything works! :) I think there Was a problem of updating! Thaks anyway.